# How to support custom fonts which does not exists in user's machine in dynamically created word file in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a tiny-mce in my code where I am editing the content with different fonts and saving it to database. Later my application is exporting a word file from this content to end user.

Now the problem is that if any font that does not exists in user's machine then word document is also not showing the content with that font instead some default font.

But the requirement of my client is that word document should support fonts even if they does not exists in user machine.

Please enlighten me if anyone have a solution of my problem.

My code to generate the word document is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301170/header-image-is-not-being-displaying-at-the-time-of-downloading-word-document-in)

Comment: 1) You can embed Fonts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727053/how-do-i-embed-a-font-with-my-c-sharp-application-using-visual-studio-2005 

2) Some Fonts have License und Distribution restriction. Keep that in mind and point that to the customer. It can also be a issue if the font is a company specific modified one.

3) Why your customer has this requierement. Does a PDF not work for this case?

Comment: Yes we are generating a PDF file also but at the same time need to generate word document too. There are two options for user either download file in PDF or in word document.